# Testing the quality of an android application

Tags: android, performance, android-testing

after searching a lot on internet i didn't get the answer I am looking.
Suppose if I made an application or if I have  downloaded another application from play store then How can I test or check whether application is well developed or not. OR in short how can I find some flows in an application.

For example :

- Application is taking more time then a benchmark time to start or
  navigating to page.
- Or its design is not good.
- It is not supported on a lot of device. etc.

Is there any platform to test an android application. Or some online resources , books or test cases using which I can follow those guideline to test or to make an efficient and better application.

As asked in comments to specify whether i am asking about well developed or a well working application. Actually i am asking about well working application for an already built application. And well developed for developing an application.

Comment: There is a big difference between a well developed or a well working application.. You can write an application with terible OO design, but still  the application would work fine. So specify your question more, what type of application etc.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, I really don't know.

For its design, you have to get real people who test it and give some feedback.

For supporting devices, you could check you Google Play Developer Console. Check the APK section, and see it.

[image: App compatability]

**For more devices:** Lower your API.

API 9 is for Android Version 2.3.3+ & API 23 is for Android 6.0 only.

So if you use a lower API, more devices can download your application.

Source: [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)

Comment: Use API as low as possible. Can you explain it more clearly.. pleasee

Comment: How lower your API, how more devices can use your application. If you use API 9, all devices starting from 2.3.3 can use your application. If you use API 23 only devices with Android 6.0 can use your application. Check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Answer (score 1):

**UI related issues  check.**

1) A phone can be built well, and have fast internals, **but if the touch(UI Designing) of the app is of poor quality**, the experience will be damaged. This is of special concern with Android.

2) Check for image quality issues

3) Sensitivity and multiple-touch

**Programming related issues  check.**

1) Detect flaws immediately and release a bug-free app straight away

2) Applause **ANALYTICS**

3) DO data testing or Load testing

4) Apps should provide the performance, stability, and responsiveness expected by users

5) From each app screen, press the device's Home key, then re-launch the app from the All Apps screen.

Or you can see more Test Procedure [Here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/core.html).